# What property of summation is used while solving this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Saw this problem on a website.
Can someone explain how the summation is split into **summation of summation**?
What property of summation was used here?
$$ T(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor. $$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
T(m^2-1) &= \sum_{k=1}^{m^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor \\ &=
\sum_{r=1}^{m-1} \sum_{\ell=r^2}^{(r+1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{\ell} \rfloor \\ &=
\sum_{r=1}^{m-1} \sum_{\ell=r^2}^{(r+1)^2-1} r
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I think you think of it more as a "Summation of summations" than as a product of summations.

Comment: @turkeyhundt:Thanks for that, can you explain how the limits were changed to convert the expression to summation of summations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the first summation indexes from $1$ to $m^2-1$.  The next line simply breaks that summation into chunks.

The left Summation indexes from $1$ to $m-1$ while the second summation will take that index and sum up to one less than the next number squared.

So, instead of one summation indexing $1,2,3,4,\dots m^2-1$, it is multiple summations. $$\Sigma_1^3 +\Sigma_4^8 +\Sigma_9^{15} +\Sigma_{16}^{24} +\dots +\Sigma_{(m-1)^2}^{m^2-1}$$

See how the next Summation always picks up where the previous one left off?

**EDIT:**  An example of another summation splitting up.

$$\text{Sum of first n numbers}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{j=2i-1}^{2i}j$$

So, for $n=6$ instead of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^6i$ it is $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^2j+\sum\limits_{j=3}^4j+\sum\limits_{j=5}^6j$$

It's kind of a dumb example because I'm not all that clever.

Comment: I couldn't have ever thought of solving problems this way. Can any summation be expressed as summation of summation? For example Sum of n numbers $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}k_i$

Comment: Sure.  I'll add to answer...

Comment: :I'd like to see that. I'll try few more myself to understand it better.

Comment: :How do you determine the upper and lower limits of the inner summation? As much as I understand, you can take anything as the upper limit for the outer summation whereas the limits of the inner summation depends on the limits of the outer summation.

Comment: It just depends on how you decide to break up the summation with the outer summation.  You just make sure that when you plug in the outer upper limit into the inner upper limit, you get your original upper limit. Think of it as $f(g(x))$.  $2\frac{n}{2}=n$ in my example gets back to the original upper limit. Just like in your original example $((m-1)+1)^2-1=m^2-1$  I'm not sure how I would come up with the breakdown in your original example without lots of exposure to summations.  I was only able to see what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Both the single sum $\displaystyle \sum_{\ell=1}^{m^2-1}$ and the nested sum $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{m-1} \sum_{\ell=r^2}^{(r+1)^2-1}$ run over the same set of values:

- for $r=1$, $\ell$ runs from $1^2 = 1$ to $2^2-1 = 3$;
- for $r=2$, $\ell$ runs from $2^2 = 4$ to $3^2-1 = 8$;
- for $r=3$, $\ell$ runs from $3^2 = 9$ to $4^2-1 = 15$;
- ...
- for $r=m-1$, $\ell$ runs from $(m-1)^2$ to $m^2-1$.